# proving parallel projection is onto

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Background information- We are given two lines L and M and point p on L. We set up a correspondence from p<==>p' between the points of line L and M requiring segment PP'|| n for all p on line L. Here is a picture
[image]

We proved in class that this mapping is one to one but now we have to prove that it is onto. Basically I have to prove that the parallel projection map f:l→m is an onto function. That is, you must prove that for any point Y on m there is a point X on l such that Y = f(X).

Here is how my proof goes but i'm not sure if its correct

Proof by Contradiction
Assume to the contrary  that this mapping is not onto. That is there exists at least one point say point x' on line M(codomain) that is not mapped to by a point on line L. We construct a line Z going through point x' and by the plane separation postulate we know that it passes through some interior point on line L say point x. Since this mapping is one to one we know  line Z only goes through point x. This is a contradiction since we assumed earlier this mapping was not onto which is clearly false.

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean geometry, the famous **parallel postulate** states that "at most one line can be drawn through any point not on a given line parallel to the given line in a plane". In fact, it is sufficient to work in affine geometry for this principle to hold. No concept of angle or length is necessary.

To show that the given projection is onto, it is sufficient to construct the preimage of every point on $M$. Thus, pick a point $P$ on the line $M$. The only line parallel to $L$ that goes through $P$ has to be $M$ according to the previous statement. Therefore, any other line through $P$ will meet $L$ at one point $P'$ (assuming that you are working in *plane* geometry). This point $P'$ is the preimage we are looking for. In conclusion, as long a $n$ is not parallel to $M$, your projection is onto.

[As a side note, I am not sure I understand what you are trying to prove when you write: "We proved earlier $f:L\to M$ is one-to-one, meaning that there has to be some distinct point on line L that line Z passes through."]

Comment: Here let me reword my proof. I want to use proof by contradiction

Comment: i'd like to know what is wrong with my proof? Thanks